# Asking for clarification of keras model.predict output

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have a model that have input size of 8 and output size of 2. But when I use model.predict using only one data, it print an 2d array of (8, 2) shape. Can anyone explain what does model.predict output actually is?

Output:

```
[[ 0.09589279  0.08555986]
 [ 0.09596384  0.08550422]
 [ 0.09589279  0.08555986]
 [ 0.09537797  0.08605254]
 [ 0.09537797  0.08605254]
 [ 0.09537797  0.08605254]
 [ 0.09537797  0.08605254]
 [ 0.09537797  0.08605254]]
```

Summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, None, 2)           16        
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, None, 256)         265216    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, None, 256)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, None, 256)         525312    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, None, 256)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, None, 256)         525312    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, None, 256)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_4 (LSTM)                (None, None, 256)         525312    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, None, 256)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_5 (LSTM)                (None, 256)               525312    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 514       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 2)                 0         
=================================================================
Total params: 2,366,994
Trainable params: 2,366,994
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

Comment: You've tagged this question with `lstm` which makes me think you're using a recurrent neural network, which _can_ have variable output lengths.

Comment: As @AaronN.Brock stated, if you used an LSTM and added `return_state = True` to the layer, your output will be `[predicted_value, last_state]`.

Comment: Please add your `model.summary()` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your input data certainly has shape `(number_of_sequences, timeSteps)`.

It's totally normal to have the output as `(number_of_sequences, 2)`, as the summary shows.

This means you have 8 sequences in your input data. Each sequence has a number of timesteps that I can't know from this summary (`None` means variable). These timesteps will be there until the last LSTM layer, where you used `return_sequences=False`.

---

In the summary:

- The first `None` = number of sequences
- The second `None` = number of timesteps